# Captioning with Tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, captions

I am trying to put a caption under the following flowchart in latex but I have not succeeded so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}      % Use this line for a4 paper
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only    needed if 
                                                      % you want to use the \thanks  command
\overrideIEEEmargins      
\usepackage{graphicx} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\newcommand\captionof[1]{\def\@captype{#1}\OrigCaption}
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, aspect =2, fill=pink!15,
text width=6em, text badly centered, node distance=4.5cm, inner sep=2pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, rounded corners, draw = blue, thick, fill=blue!16,
text width=9em, text centered, minimum height=3em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, very thick, color=black!60, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=purple!20, node distance=3.0cm,
minimum height=1em]

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, node distance = 1.4cm, auto]
% Place nodes
\node [block] (init) {Construct and Save an OpenNI Depth Context};
\node [cloud, left of=init, node distance=4cm] (start) {Initialization};
\node [block, below of=init, node distance=1.6cm] (DepthGen) {Create a Depth      Generator};
\node [block, below of=DepthGen, node distance=1.6cm] (MapOutput) {Create a Depth Data Map};
\node [block, left of=MapOutput, node distance=4cm] (update) {Continuously Update Depth Images in Context Map};
\node [block, below of=MapOutput, node distance=1.6cm] (MapResolution) {Get 2D map resolution coordinates};
\node [block, below of=MapResolution, node distance=1.6cm] (Midpoint) {Retrieve midpoint of depth coordinates};
\node [block, below of=Midpoint, node distance=1.6cm] (send) {Send coordinates to myRIO via UDP packets};
\node [decision, below of=send, node distance=2.2cm] (decide) {Missing Frame Data?};
\node [block, left of=decide, node distance=4.5cm] (Yes) {Use previous frame's depth data};
\node [block, below of=decide, node distance=2.1cm] (no) {Apply FIR point-by-point filter};
\node [block, below of=no, node distance=1.6cm] (Use) {Pass on measurement data to control patient head};

% Draw edges
\path [line] (init) -- (DepthGen);
\path [line, dashed] (DepthGen) - | (update);
\path [line, dashed] (start) -- (init);
\path [line] (DepthGen) -- (MapOutput);
\path [line] (MapOutput) -- (MapResolution);
\path [line] (MapResolution) -- (Midpoint); 
\path [line] (Midpoint) -- (send); 
\path [line] (send) -- (decide); 
\path [line] (decide) -- (no); 
\path [line] (decide) -- node [near start, color=black] {Yes} (Yes);
\path [line] (decide) -- node [near start, color=black] {No} (no);
\path [line, dashed] (Yes) |- (no);
\path [line] (no) -- (Use);

\end{tikzpicture} 

\caption{Vision Algorithm Flowchart}
\label{Fig. 3.}


\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I tried using the `\captionof{some caption}` command too but no luck.
I would appreciate your insight!

Comment: Once you turn your snippet into a complete correct document (adding `\documentclass{article}`, `\end{document}`, moving `\usepackage` commands before `\begin{document}`) your code produces a caption for the figure. Can you please describe in detail what seems to be the problem in your case? And, first of all, please edit your question and turn your example code into a complete and correct LaTeX document.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! See Gonzalo Medina's comment about the MWE

Comment: @GonzaloMedina , I have made the edit in my original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}      % Use this line for a4 paper
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts                              % This command is only       needed if 
                                                  % you want to use the \thanks  command
\overrideIEEEmargins      
\usepackage{graphicx} % for pdf, bitmapped graphics files
\usepackage{times} % assumes new font selection scheme installed
\usepackage{amsmath} % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{amssymb}  % assumes amsmath package installed
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, draw, aspect =2, fill=pink!15,
text width=6em, text badly centered, node distance=4.5cm, inner sep=2pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, rounded corners, draw = blue, thick, fill=blue!16,
text width=9em, text centered, minimum height=3em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, very thick, color=black!60, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=purple!20, node distance=3.0cm,
minimum height=1em]

% Draw Flowchart of Vision Program
\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4, node distance = 1.4cm, auto]
% Place nodes
\node [block] (init) {Construct and Save an OpenNI Depth Context};
\node [cloud, left of=init, node distance=4cm] (start) {Initialization};
\node [block, below of=init, node distance=1.6cm] (DepthGen) {Create a Depth      Generator};
\node [block, below of=DepthGen, node distance=1.6cm] (MapOutput) {Create a Depth Data Map};
\node [block, left of=MapOutput, node distance=4cm] (update) {Continuously Update Depth Images in Context Map};
\node [block, below of=MapOutput, node distance=1.6cm] (MapResolution) {Get 2D map resolution coordinates};
\node [block, below of=MapResolution, node distance=1.6cm] (Midpoint) {Retrieve midpoint of depth coordinates};
\node [block, below of=Midpoint, node distance=1.6cm] (send) {Send coordinates to myRIO via UDP packets};
\node [decision, below of=send, node distance=2.2cm] (decide) {Missing Frame Data?};
\node [block, left of=decide, node distance=4.5cm] (Yes) {Use previous frame's depth data};
\node [block, below of=decide, node distance=2.1cm] (no) {Apply FIR point-by-point filter};
\node [block, below of=no, node distance=1.6cm] (Use) {Pass on measurement data to control patient head};

% Draw edges
\path [line] (init) -- (DepthGen);
\path [line, dashed] (DepthGen) - | (update);
\path [line, dashed] (start) -- (init);
\path [line] (DepthGen) -- (MapOutput);
\path [line] (MapOutput) -- (MapResolution);
\path [line] (MapResolution) -- (Midpoint); 
\path [line] (Midpoint) -- (send); 
\path [line] (send) -- (decide); 
\path [line] (decide) -- (no); 
\path [line] (decide) -- node [near start, color=black] {Yes} (Yes);
\path [line] (decide) -- node [near start, color=black] {No} (no);
\path [line, dashed] (Yes) |- (no);
\path [line] (no) -- (Use);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\captionof{figure}{Vision Algorithm Flowchart}
\label{Fig. 3.}
\end{center}\end{minipage}
% end of flowchart code
```

Comment: In its present state you might get undesired results; you need to place `\captionof` inside a group, box or environment (otherwise, bad things could happen).

Comment: Into a \groupbox? How do you mean?

Comment: No, into a group or a box or an environment (which, by default forms a group). My suggestion would be to use the `center` environment and anclose the whole thing inside a `minipage` (to prevent the caption from being dettached from the figure). Schematically: `\begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}\captionof{figure}{...}\label{...}\end{center}\end{minipage}`

Comment: Oh, okay! I see. Thanks for the info. Cheers!